# Put a link over the right border

Tags: css, html, nav

The following script would generate a display like this:

```
<style>
    nav { position: fixed; left: 10em; top: 5em; border-right: 100px solid #0000cc; box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);}
</style>
<body>
    <nav><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
        <ul>
            <li>White</li>
            <li>Blue</li>
            <li>Yellow</li>
            <li>Black</li>
            <li>Green</li>
            <li>Orange</li>
            <li>Pink</li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Magenta</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

[image]

I would like google.com link located on the right border as shown below:
[image]

how to fix those script ?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Try by using `position: absolute` and then set `left` to some amount of pixels. Can you please show what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Output]

Here is a [working fiddle for your problem](https://jsfiddle.net/Somu2016/hs25a36m/3/).

I've simply added an ID to your link, called "floatingLink", changed the color of the link to white (#fff) and positioned it absolutely. Change the top and/or left properties to adjust the position.

The code that achieves it is:

```
#floatingLink {
  color:#fff;
  position : absolute;
  left: 7.5em; 
  top: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

block the a label first and then you need to design it with absolute position then you can place it anywhere within the element of its parent element.Last you can put it anywhere you want inside it,here it's the demo i made,I think it can satisfy your request:

```
a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <style>
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        left: 10em;
        top: 5em;
        border-right: 100px solid #0000cc;
        box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
    a {
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        top: 4.5em;
        right: 19em;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>White</li>
                <li>Blue</li>
                <li>Yellow</li>
                <li>Black</li>
                <li>Green</li>
                <li>Orange</li>
                <li>Pink</li>
                <li>Red</li>
                <li>Magenta</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/" style="float:right;">Google</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this....

Comment: <html>

<style>
    nav {position: fixed; left: 10em; top: 5em; border-right: 100px solid #0000cc; box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);}
 a {color:white; position:relative;top:4.5em;right:19em;}
</style>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>White</li>
            <li>Blue</li>
            <li>Yellow</li>
            <li>Black</li>
            <li>Green</li>
            <li>Orange</li>
            <li>Pink</li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Magenta</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
 <a href="http://www.google.com/" style="float:right;">Google</a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: To put a block of code in an answer, indent it with 4 spaces in the markdown. Make sure to properly indent code also. I've made edits to try to fix your answer.